# SQL simplification. LEFT JOIN ON by different conditions

Tags: sql

How to simplify SQL expression and designate the table "USERS" as one "AS" (if `gs.USER_ID IS NULL` then go to the next left join)?

```
LEFT JOIN USERS as u1
    ON u1.USER_ID = gs.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN USERS as u2
    ON u2.USER_ID = pt.USER_ID
...
ISNULL(u1.USER_ID, u2.USER_ID) as UserId,
ISNULL(u1.EMAIL, u2.EMAIL) as UserEmail,
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN USERS AS u ON (u.USER_ID = gs.USER_ID OR u.USER_ID = pt.USER_ID)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
LEFT JOIN USERS as u1
    ON (u1.USER_ID = gs.USER_ID OR (gs.USER_ID is null AND u1.USER_ID = pt.USER_ID))
```